# List info about files/directories with spaces

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, awk, ls

I am trying to use ls to get information about files and directories. My current command fails to properly get the name whenever a file/directory has a space.

I am using this to list all files/directories in a directory:

```
ls -al --time-style=+%s . | awk '{if ($7 != ".." && $7 != "." && $1 != "total") print $1"\t"$3"\t"$5"\t"$6"\t"$7}'
```

Say I have 3 directories in my pwd "no-spaces-dir", "some dir", "some other dir", this would be the output:

```
drwxr-xr-x.     testuser    4096    1349853378      no-space-dir
drwxr-xr-x.     testuser    4096    1349853387      some
drwxr-xr-x.     testuser    4096    1349853359      two
```

I'm going to say this is an issue with my awk part. So $7 *should* be the directory name, and obviously I could just add $8 and $9 to get my desired output for the example I set up, but I may not always know a directory will only have 1 or 2 spaces..

How can I keep this other information present (file/directory permissions, user, space, timestamp) and also get the full name in the command's output?

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), use `find` or a loop...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that awk is parsing the input with white space as field separators. This makes for trouble when you have whitespace as part of a field.

Instead of parsing the output of `ls`, you can use `stat(1)` to get what you want along with the "dotglob" bash shell option.

```
shopt -s dotglob  # Enable * to match files starting with a dot
stat -c $'%A\t%U\t%s\t%Y\t%n' *
```

The format string outputs the fields you wanted in the format you wanted. The use of $'...' allows the \t to be expanded to a tab. You could insert an actual tab character and drop the leading $ if you wanted.

Read the `bash(1)` man page for details on dotglob, and pay attention to GLOBIGNORE. Read the `stat(1)` man page for what you can put in a format string.

Comment: This works wonderfully! I wasn't aware of `stat`. I like the ability to specify other parameters or a parameter in a different format like that. The GLIBIGNORE info was also useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, parsing `ls` is not the best way to print the content of directory. You problem can be easily solved, however.

As file/directory name is always last column (or columns), instead of printing $7, you can print from $7 to last column. You can do this with:

```
substr($0, index($0, $7))
```

So your full command would be:

```
ls -al --time-style=+%s . | awk '{if ($7 != ".." && $7 != "." && $1 != "total") print $1"\t"$3"\t"$5"\t"$6"\t" substr($0,index($0,$7));}'
```

Also note that checking if `$1 != "total"` is not really good idea since it won't work on localized systems (where `total` may be other word). I suggest using `NF>6` to ensure you have enough columns.

Comment: To eliminate the `total` line, skip line 1: `… && NR != 1`

Comment: Thanks for letting me know how to do it with my old way. I switched to use `stat`, but it was good for me to see a way to do it with `awk`. I'm still learning about things like `awk`, so the substr method and the NF thing was helpful.